# javafx doesn't launch the video

Tags: java, video, javafx

I tried to play a video in a javafx app; this is my code:

public class Video extends Application{

```
private String Dir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\out\\video";
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(Dir, "test.mp4");
    Media media = new Media(f.toURI().toURL().toString());
    MediaPlayer player = new   javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer(media);
    MediaView viewer = new MediaView(player);
    player.setOnReady(() -> {
        player.setStartTime(Duration.ZERO);
        player.setStopTime(media.getDuration().subtract(Duration.valueOf("50")));
    });

    player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> player.stop());

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(viewer);
    Scene scenes = new Scene(root, 500, 500, Color.BLACK);
    stage.setScene(scenes);
    stage.setTitle("Riddle Game");
    stage.setFullScreen(true);
    stage.show();
    player.play();
}
```

}

But when I launch the app, it shows a black window and the video is not played.
I don't understand my mistake

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT : Still don't work...

Comment: There is no system property with key `"./out/video/"`.

Comment: You right, my bad, but I changed the code (cf the code in the question) and it still don't work... Have you an other idea ?

Comment: Does the file exist? What does `System.out.println(f.exists());` give?

Comment: I have already tested that, the file is found... It return "true"

Comment: Then not sure. Maybe the video contained in the mp4 file uses an encoding that is not supported (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html)) for a list of supported encodings. Perhaps test with a different video file? There doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong in your code. Try `player.errorProperty().addListener((obs, oldErr, newErr) -> { if (newErr != null) newErr.printStackTrace(); });`.